# Why don’t SMTP servers just require all senders to be authenticated before accepting mail?

Tags: encryption, authentication, network, email, smtp

Why don’t SMTP servers just require all senders to be 
authenticated before accepting mail?

Comment: "SMTP" as in `smtp.my.isp` (which do not implement the real SMTP protocol), or the real SMTP servers, as found in `MX` records?

Comment: Can't their admins be charged for open SMTP servers?

Answer (score 6):

Laziness mostly. Ease of configuration, it's easier for administrators to setup a central SMTP server which doesn't require authentication to send email, than one that does.

You will often see that this is also offered by ISPs to accomodate their clients more easily.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are making the following assumption:

- The clients of SMTP servers are a finite set of physical users that can be associated with some form of identity and therefore have accounts which can be used to authenticate and authorize them.

This is only half the story.

- Authentication can (*and should*) be enforced when clients are attempting to use an SMTP server in order to relay an e-mail to a user on a remote domain. The lack of authentication and recipient control mechanisms during this phase is considered bad practice and such servers are called *"open relays"* since they allow anyone to use them in order to relay e-mails anywhere.
- The other half of the story is when you receive e-mails. The "sender" in this case is another SMTP server that is connecting to your SMTP server and uses it to send a message to you. Enforcing authentication during this phase would mean that every legit SMTP server on the planet would have to have an account on every other legit SMTP server on the planet, in order to be able to send e-mails to anyone. Keeping all these accounts in sync would be a major challenge and administrative overhead.

For example, not many things prevent Trudy from connecting to a *mail-provider-a* SMTP server and sending an e-mail to alice@mail-provider-a.com while listing bob@mail-provider-b.com as the sender. mail-provider-a has no way to verify mail-provider-b users. This is not a misconfiguration, this is how the e-mail works.

[SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records can be used in order to verify remote SMTP servers and mitigate the above attack, by making sure the sender's IP address matches the IP address specified in the SPF record for the domain that is being claimed as the e-mail origin. This is not enforced being enforced by many email providers.

This is the reason that people should use e-mail signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Email dates from an earlier time. Spam was not an issue and impersonation was not a major issue, lack of connectivity was an issue. The normal behaviour for an email server was to forward mail for anyone who asked. Nowadays open relaying will get you shunned but one has to understand that authentication is something that has been gradually bolted on to email, not a core part of the design.

The mail handled by a mailserver can be broadly split into "incoming" and "outgoing".

"outgoing" mail will be relayed to the server associated with the destination email address. To avoid being shunned as an open relay the mailserver admin must implement some kind of restriction on who can use the server as a relay. IP based restrictions are a common method because they do not require any client configuration or user database management.

"incoming" mail may be stored locally or relayed to another internal mailserver. Such mail may come from anyone on the Internet, so it's difficult to implement access restrictions. Some would like to introduce restrictions to try and ensure that the sender was who they claim to be but the existance of mailing lists and mail-forwarding services complicates this.